# Form Data being posted twice via XMLHttpRequest, once as an empty object and once with the correct data

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, xmlhttprequest

I am learning web development and in that, AJAX. For this particular example I am using the XMLHttpRequest object on the browser and Node with Express as my server.
I have a simple HTML form that needs to post data to a Node server. I know that data is being posted successfully, because, I can see the Form Data in the chrome's Network tab.

I have a couple of problems with my code and I've looked for answers on Stackoverflow and also looked at the MDN documentation for the past three days, but am unable to figure this.

The questions below are with respect to the posted code:

1. If submitForm() returns true, I have the data posted twice to the server, once with an empty request body and once with the expected data. Why? 
   [Post Data when submitForm() returns true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsVOJ.jpg)
2. If submitForm() returns false, no data is posted back to the server. Why?
   [Post Data when submitForm() returns false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjXjR.jpg)
3. If there is no call to submitForm() at all (ie. sans a call to XHR), then the form data is posted correctly and this is seen in the req.body on the server side. 
   [Result of POST when there is no onSubmit event attached to the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihY7e.jpg)
4. If I set the RequestHeader on xhr to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7E2A.jpg) is what I get.
5. How do I get the form to post data to the server using XMLHTTPRequest?

I am completely lost and am not sure what I am missing. If someone can throw some light, I would appreciate that greatly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge, chrome=1"/>

<script>
"use strict";
function submitForm()
{
  var formElement = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var formData = new FormData(formElement);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/Test", true);
  xhr.send(formData);
  //return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/Test" onsubmit="return submitForm();" >
   <input type="text" value="John" name="name"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Send Data"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//Server side code (NodeJS)
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./'));

var urlencoded = bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true});

app.get('/Test', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/Test.html');
});

app.post('/Test', urlencoded, function(req, res){
  console.log("In POST");
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/Test.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Now listening on port 8080...');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking through your code and testing it out myself. I found out that...

1. To answer the first question, you are actually submitting the data "John" twice. The first time was through your "submitForm()" function. The second time was through the  element attributes method="POST", action="/Test".
2. The submitForm function is actually working but you are using XMLHttpRequest() to send the post request to the server. If you read the documentation, XMLHttpRequest uses multipart/form-data enctype to send the form data. Therefore your route must be able to handle multipart/form-data format.
3. To find out if your submitForm() function is indeed called, you could always add a alert(' into the function. If it is called, a prompt will pop up. Always a great way to debug!
4. Format sent by XMLHttpRequest(): multipart/form-data, format handled: urlencoded, a bit of a mismatch here
5. Finally let's get to the solution. Like I said your route needs to be able to handle multipart/form-data.

var express = require('express');// I have no idea why I couldn't format this line to code :/

```
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer') // Use this module to add a middleware onto your route
var mult_handler = multer() // creates a handler object

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./'));

var urlencoded = bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true});

app.get('/Test', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/Test.html');
});

app.post('/Test', mult_handler.none(), function(req, res){ 
    console.log("In POST");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/Test.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Now listening on port 8080...');
```

Comment: Thanks so much  for taking the time to answer @CodeCodey. Handling the route for the content-type did fix my issue. I tried your solution; it worked,  except that I had to use mult_handler.none() to get it to working. Just mult_handler errors with: "Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]".  

So, what is the widely-accepted-practice of posting an HTML form? Should you always return a false on form submit, or should you do away with the POST and action attribute on the form, or should you completely ignore the XHR route since the button posts the form anyways?

Comment: I'm so dumb I didn't copy the none() part haha anyways we would need some further debugging on the object error, encountered it once before but I kinda forgot how to solve it. For me, I would just use the form element just as it is using attribute of action and method to send data back to server. Then my route would accept application/json cuz it's so much simpler to handle and read. That's my preference, keep things simple so that it's easy everyone to understand.

Comment: Update on the "Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]" error, please remove the comment on the "// replace your url...mult-handler" because I am getting that problem as well. I think the editor(repl.it) couldn't fit the whole comment so the compiler treat it as a code. Remove it and you're good to go. P.S. I have updated the answer to show that as well.

Comment: So if you use the form's method and action attributes, would you use body-parser or multer? I ask because, body-parser would be able to read application/json.

Comment: yup I would use bodyParser json